# Django | Cannot assign object: instance isn't saved in the (wrong?) database

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I want to create a `User` that has a reference to a `People` entry - a different table in the same database. I do

```
person = People(firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname)
person.save()

newuser = User(username=username, person=person)
newuser.save()
```

But although I explicitly saved `person`, it tells me

```
Cannot assign "<People: People object>": "People" instance isn't saved in the database.
```

**Edit:** Changed the question to better reflect the situation - and the answer below.

Comment: Did you read this: [Limitations of multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases)?

Comment: Yes, and it is not cross-databases in my case. The two tables are in `MY_DB`, and the foreign key is between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it happens not only with non default dbs, but with the default as well. The problem was that with MySQL, primary key fields have to be `AutoField(primary_key=True)` and not `IntegerField(primary_key=True)` (which used to work with sqlite).